# Can a custom constraint route to multiple controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I am using a custom constraint that is linked to a single route like:

```
get '/hello', to: 'account#index', 
        constraints: AccountConstraint.new
```

Basically my custom constraint is looking up the request.host, and if it is found in the database the matches? method will return true and then the account#index action will get called.

What I want to do is, if the constraint matches, then based on the path it will go do a different action.

So my constraint would be like:

```
class AccountConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    # lookup the database, return true if record found
  end
end
```

Then I want my route.rb file to do something like this (pseudo code below_:

```
if AccountConstraint matches
  get '/', to: "account#index"
  get '/hello', to: "account#hello"
end
```

**Is something like this possible? If so, how?**

Comment: I would write that sort of logic inside the controller rather than in the routes file. You can check in the controller if the request matches or even in the view.

Comment: You should use controller to check the referer/host  from request in controller rather than routes and redirect accordingly...It will be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question, but it sounds like what you want is a `scope`:

```
scope constraints: AccountConstraint.new do
  get '/', to: "account#index"
  get '/hello', to: "account#hello"
end
```

The routes inside the scope will only be accessible if `AccountConstraint` matches.